# Joomla form field required even though required attribute changed to false

Tags: php, forms, validation, joomla

I have a form with a field that is required in some instances and not in others so I have changed the required attribute on the fly in the edit view file with the setFieldAttribute function:

```
if (_condition_) {
    $this->form->setFieldAttribute('transprice', 'required', 'false');
}
```

this works and is reflected in the html output.

However when I try to save the form I'm still getting:

> Warning
>
> Field required: Transfer Price

Is there something else I need to consider to get this to work?

Comment: You have to change the xml form too.

Comment: @JobinJose Do you mean the actual file? If so then that won't work because I need to be able to change it depending on a certain condition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing all your code it's hard to answer this question but our best option would be to use javascript to set and unset the required part of this field. If you're using a form that uses Validation.js then you can dynamically set the `requrired` class on the page via javascript.

So long answer short:
1) Leave it un-required in the XML. Because if you're using JForm, JForm is going to rely on that no matter what you set.

2) Dynamically set the required class so validation.js can refer to it and see if the form should be required or not. This is only a client side validation.

3) For server side validation you will need to override the data model and the controller to determine (again) if the field should be required based on your other dynamic data.

Read more about that here: http://docs.joomla.org/Form_field#Client-side_validation

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I was hoping it was going to be a simpler solution than that but I must say I'm surprised that Joomla always goes back to the xml... It doesn't make sense (to me at least) that it doesn't look at the form instance for validation.

Comment: With JForm it's going to rely on the XML because the XML saves you from hand-writing the model yourself. It refers to the XML to  line up everything like the form names, the column names in the database, the required status, etc... You'll notice when you load your JForm into the model it refers directly to the XML file right in the model:

JForm:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_contact/models/forms/contact.xml

Model:
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_contact/models/contact.php#L73

Comment: Yeah I thought that was the case. I think my only options are to override the model and controller or better still to create a custom validation rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a field required, except in some cases, you can dynamically set this in the getForm-Function in the Model, but you have to unset the filter as well.

```
class ComponentnameModelViewname extends JModelAdmin{

    public function getForm($data = array(), $loadData = true){

         $form = $this->loadForm('com_componentname.listviewname', 'viewname', array('control' => 'jform', 'load_data' => $loadData));

         if (empty($form)) {
               return false;
         }

         if ($condition) {
               $form->setFieldAttribute('fieldname', 'required', 'false');
               $form->setFieldAttribute('fieldname', 'filter', 'unset');
         }

         return $form;
    }

}
```